# stop else if condition jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm newbie in this forum and I'm having some issue in my jquery script. I have a form with many input text and I take each of them and I see if its value is empty. In my input file, I test if the extension's file is png or jpg, if not, a modal appears informing the correct file. The problem lies here, I can't get out from this step, my script simply doesn't work anymore. Here it's my jquery script ..

```js
var foto = $("#fotoperfil").val();


// There are more else if above this
else if (senha != con_senha) {
  erro.fadeIn().html("As senhas não conferem");
  $("#senha").parent().addClass("has-error");
  $("#con_senha").parent().addClass("has-error");

} else if (foto != "") {
  //recupero a extensão deste nome de arquivo 
  extensao = (foto.substring(foto.lastIndexOf("."))).toLowerCase();
  //alert (extensao);
  if (extensao != arquivo[0] && extensao != arquivo[1]) {
    erro.fadeIn().html("Somente arquivos .jpg e .png são permitidos");
  }
}

// There are more else if below that
```

The condition must be stopped when the user submit a valid file, if the input file is not empty, and the script keeps validating the other inputs.

Comment: I will suggest you to use jQuery validator library.

Comment: What you mean by _my script simply doesn't work anymore_? If you get exception show error message and line where it is thrown. If you get wrong result show wrong result and result you expect and code which produce this result

Comment: arquivo is an array with png and jpg? If yes, add an else after this if statement.

Comment: its "AND" `if (extensao != arquivo[0] && extensao != arquivo[1])` did you mean "OR" `||`

Comment: @Fabio, it doesn't show any message. This input is the last one before my submit form. If I comment this piece of code, I can submit my form via ajax.

>> xxLITxx - I've already did that but it doesn't work to. It does not keep executing the script.

>> ewwink - It's actually "and", not "or". I have an array with jpg and png indexes, so if the file is not jpg AND neither png, the submit cannot be executed.